# Edit HTML Response before sending

Tags: java, http, response

I have a webservice that is going to receive a request, perform an action in java, and then return a response as standard.

The client expecting the response however, is expecting the HTTP response to have two characters appended to the end of the message (any, it does not matter, currently just \n\n, and for reasons unknown to me - it's legacy code), outside of the headers and body.

Presently it is done by sending the HTTP message first to a proxy, which appends the characters and forwards the message, but does anyone know of a way that this can be done in java without the need for a proxy?

I.e. - Can I access the full HTML response to edit it before it is sent?

Edit: The client is not a browser, but an application sending SOAP messages.

Comment: Yes, You can do that. It depends upon how u send response to browser.

Comment: The response is not sent to the browser but as a SOAP message from an application to the service and back?

Comment: Are you running this in a servlet spec? Tomcat? If so you can do it with a filter.

Comment: @Krroae27 Not presently, but there are changes afoot, so could you expand? Thanks!

Comment: I added as answer since it was a large block of code.

Comment: Will give it a try and get back to you, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using apache-cxf interceptors, as we only needed the full SOAP message in the end. By adding an outgoing interceptor that converted the SoapMessage content to a string, added the two characters and set the content again, our issue was fixed.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is being ran as a webserver following the servlet spec you could use a filter.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebFilter(asyncSupported = true, filterName = "LegacyAppender", urlPatterns = { "/paths/tofile" })
public class AppendFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        HttpServletResponse hsr = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        hsr.getWriter().print("\r\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

    }
}
```